# Android Glance Widget - How to update each full hour?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, glance-appwidget, glance

I have an Flutter app that shows data that are refreshed each hour.
Many users have requested a widget and I went on the task to fix it for Android and iOS.
My experience with Kotlin and Swift was "near zero", so a total noob. I need a more experience dev to give me a direction on how to handle Android.

Just finished up the widget in iOS and it was really neat and pretty easy to implement.
Apple had good guides and a clear how the widget data is handled and what to expect by the system regarding to background handling.

Now I am trying to create the same success on Android and I wanted to use "Glance" as this was the most modern design. Guides for implement data was OK and the state-handling was clear. But to update the widget each hour is pain:

- Workmanager is not triggered on the hour whole hour (can be delayed for minutes)
- Workmanager is not started when app starts (restart of phone makes your widget static, need a click to get it going again)

My resources for learning this was

- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/glance/glance-app-widget
- https://dev.to/tkuenneth/updating-widgets-introduction-4cof
- https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/blob/39741e7f101e397811815ab9c7d456ad00d099a7/AppWidget/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/appwidget/glance/weather/WeatherWorker.kt

Are there any "timeline" data handling in Android like iOS does? Or are all widgets based on a timer with highly restrictions, making the experience pretty lousy?

Comment: Unclear if you've read: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Comment: Have you taken a look at this sample : https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:glance/glance-appwidget/samples/src/main/java/androidx/glance/appwidget/samples/GlanceAppWidgetSamples.kt;drc=c28b42063433bb0f928a897c0d6ec31b45ba2021;l=114

Comment: I looked into it, but this method will not update the widget if the app is started/installed within less than 15 min until next hour. Currently trying to use alarmmanager to handle this in a better manner. Not quite in goal yet, but close